# Refreshing listview after deleteing database entry

Tags: java, android

Im aware I need to use the arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged, but I'm not sure where to implement this, deleting database entries occurs within the onItemLongClick. Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

After deleting the entry the page must be refreshed in order for the listview to take the changes on board.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `onClick()` listener, after the item is deleted from the database, you must delete it from `list` and notify the adapter:

```
@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
    delete.removeValue();
    list.remove(i);
    arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    Toast.makeText(list_view.this, "Report deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```